# How can I get the number of Videos a Facebook Page has posted using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to get the total number of video posts from a page. The way I can do it now is by getting an array of all videos using the field `fields=videos` like so. But I don't want an array of videos, I want just the number of videos. Does Facebook have a call like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API endpoint or field for this.

---

This is just to unusual a requirement; the majority of apps will likely never need that kind of information. And since “counting” such stuff is quite demanding on the system (aspects like privacy settings, targeting options etc. in relation to the specific access token used would have to be taken into account), it is not implemented.